# in sudoers, how to test if an alias is already defined, to avoid dupl definitions

Tags: linux, sudo

I need to enable a command for several users, enabled as users are created. Currently I have something like (on an SLES 12 SP1 Linux)

```
Cmnd_Alias S3CP = /usr/local/bin/prog param1 param2 * # constraining usage
u1 ALL=(u1-helper) NOPASSWD: S3CP
u2 ALL=(u2-helper) NOPASSWD: S3CP
u3 ALL=(u3-helper) NOPASSWD: S3CP
# etc...
```

What I would like to do is take these local embellishments out of the main conf and put them into `/etc/sudoers.d/` so as to better manage changes to configs

```
90-myapp-u1.conf # containing the Cmnd_Alias and the authorization
90-myapp-u2.conf # similarly
```

But this might cause duplicate `Cmnd_Alias` definitions from second user onwards. Is there a way to check if an alias is already defined and skip a command? Analogous to a MATCH rule or #ifndef. OR, is there some other, idiomatic way to do the same? I don't want to inline the command alias.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The best fragment solution would probably be to simply put your S3CP into its own fragement separate from the usage of it.  So do something like this.  It would then be on your configuration managment system to make sure that s3cp is always installed before adding any other fragments that attempt to use it.

/etc/sudoers.d/s3cp

```
Cmnd_Alias S3CP = /usr/local/bin/prog param1 param2 * # constraining usage
```

/etc/sudoers.d/u1

```
u1 ALL=(u1-helper) NOPASSWD: S3CP
```

/etc/sudoers.d/u2

```
u2 ALL=(u2-helper) NOPASSWD: S3CP
```

/etc/sudoers.d/u3

```
u3 ALL=(u3-helper) NOPASSWD: S3CP
```

Comment: If there is no ifndef-like feature then I will take suggested approach - it's clean and I can easily integrate it in user creation

Comment: If I define the cmnd_alias in included file 1 and try to use it in file 2, I get 2 warnings - first on file 1, saying alias defined but not used; and second on file 2, saying no alias defined. Is there some other setting required for the aliases to have cross-file visibility?

Comment: I assume you are using visudo or something when you are getting this error?  I cheated, and just used a standard text editor and so never saw any warnings.  If you chose to do this, it is important to test on a non-production system first.

Comment: You are right, I was using visudo, and the aliases did not take effect. I will try more ways on my test machine because I like the approach.